# NoMethodError: undefined method `validate_presence_of' (Rspec and Shoulda-Matchers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, shoulda

I'm trying to set up Rspec and Shoulda-Matchers, but for some reason I get this error:

> NoMethodError:
>           undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdCampaign::Validations:0x000000062a2b90>
>
> Failure/Error: it { should have_many :advertisements }
>          expected # to respond to `has_many?`
>
> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `belong_to' for #RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdCampaign::Associations:0x0000000686d8e0>

It seems that I tried every answer from stackoverflow and github issues, and nothing helps.

Maybe you could help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'spec_helper'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

and here's my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
  # config.include Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model
  # config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.order = 'random'

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

heer's the spec file with my tests:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AdCampaign, type: :model do
  describe 'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of :shop }
    it { should validate_presence_of :description }
  end

  describe 'associations' do
    it { should belong_to :shop }
    it { should have_many :advertisements }
    it { should have_one :recipient_list }
  end
end
```

and here's the model I'm trying to test:

```
class AdCampaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :advertisements
  has_one :recipient_list

  validates :shop, :description, presence: true
end
```

---

I've tried placing `Shoulda::Matchers.configure do...` in both `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`.

And in my gem file I have `shoulda-matchers` gem like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end
```

---

Could you please help me with setting up shoulda-matchers and rspec? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried removing shoulda-matchers out of `:development` group?

Comment: @HoangPhan yep, didn't help, the same errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Which rails and ruby do you have this problem?

Comment: @HoangPhan Here's the output from the console:

`$ ruby -v ===> ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]`

`$ rails -v ===> Rails 4.2.5`

Comment: Strange, I entered the exact same things with the exact environment as yours and it works. The error looks like you haven't installed the gem, maybe you could try `bundle` or `bundle update` again?

Comment: @HoangPhan Just tried both `bundle` and `bundle update`, and also tried running `gem install shoulda-matchers` and `gem install shoulda`, but still the same errors. Weird...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem! Me helped this:

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem "shoulda-matchers", require: false
end
```

And this is to add to the top rspec_helper.rb

```
require 'shoulda-matchers'

require "bundler/setup"
::Bundler.require(:default, :test)

::Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec
    #with.test_framework :minitest
    #with.test_framework :minitest_4
    #with.test_framework :test_unit

    # Choose one or more libraries:
    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    #with.library :action_controller
    # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
    #with.library :rails
  end
end
```